# Trying to Sum data within a selected time period (in decimal years data)

Tags: worksheet-function, time, range

Snip from Excel showing data I am using, I am trying to Sum column "Cum.Fire" but only want to select data starting from 2019.667 in the "time in decimal column".

[image: Snip from Excel showing data I am using, I am trying to Sum column "Cum.Fire" but only want to select data starting from 2019.667 in the "time in decimal column", how do I do this]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
=SUM( ( "BeginningDate:LastDate" >= "First date" ) * ( "BeginningDate:LastDate" <= "End date" ) * ( "Cum. Fire column" ) )
```

It simply creates three arrays, the first tests each date for being greater than or equal to your starting date, the second tests each date for being less than or equal to the ending date, and the final is an array of the values you wish to sum.

Since there is multiplication (or any other convenient arithmetic operation) performed on the arrays, Excel is coerced into treating their TRUE/FALSE entries as 1/0 entries. Any FALSE entry will result in that row's multiplication ending up as 0.00 regardless of the other two arrays. Any row with 1's for the first two arrays will output the value in the Cum. Fire column for the row.

The resulting single array it outputs is then 0's for rows that do not meet the conditions, and Cum. Fire column values for rows that do meet them.

`SUM` then adds all that up.